# Setting max date value to current date OR 1 year from start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

What should I do to restrict the user to select the end date beyond one year from the starting date OR the current date. I have my codes like this.

```
$(function () {
$('#DateFrom').datepicker({
    dateFormat:'d-M-y',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: new Date(2000, 7, 23), 
    maxDate: 0,
    onSelect: function() {
        var date = $('#DateFrom').datepicker('getDate');
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000*60*60*24*365));
        $('#DateTo').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
        $('#DateTo').datepicker('option', 'minDate',$('#DateFrom').datepicker('getDate'));
        displayToUser();
    },

});

$('#DateTo').datepicker({
    dateFormat:'d-M-y',
    maxDate: 0,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: displayToUser,
});
});
function displayToUser() {}
```

Here although it restricts the user within one year from starting date, but it allows the user to select dates beyond the current date.

Example: if start date is 23-01-2016, it allows to select the end date upto 22-01-2017. I want it to be at most today's date.

Comment: Let me know if my solution works :)

Comment: it worked. but i am facing one more issue now. can you please help me in how to clear the date picker values on selecting a radio button? 

I have two radio buttons, and both shows calendar on selecting. i need to clear one calendar value on selecting the other radio button.

Comment: issue got resolved.

onclick="$('selector').datepicker('setDate', null) did the trick. let me know if there is some better solution.

Comment: I think your solution is the best one

Comment: Adding 365 days will fail over leap year boundaries, e.g. 2015-03-01 plus 365 days is 29-02-2016. Just add 1 year to the year: `date.setYear(date.getYear() + 1)`. Adding 1 year to 29 Feb will return 1 March. If you want it to be 28 Feb, check the month and if it's different, set the date to zero (last day of previous month). Otherwise, leave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do it?

```
$(function () {
    $('#DateFrom').datepicker({
        dateFormat:'d-M-y',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(2000, 7, 23), 
        maxDate: 0,
        onSelect: function() {
            var date = $('#DateFrom').datepicker('getDate');
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000*60*60*24*365));
            var todaysDate = new Date();
            if(date.getTime() > todaysDate.getTime()) date = todaysDate;
            $('#DateTo').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
            $('#DateTo').datepicker('option', 'minDate',$('#DateFrom').datepicker('getDate'));
            displayToUser();
        },

    });

    $('#DateTo').datepicker({
        dateFormat:'d-M-y',
        maxDate: 0,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: displayToUser,
    });
});
function displayToUser() {}
```

I only added these two lines

```
            var todaysDate = new Date();
            if(date.getTime() > todaysDate.getTime()) date = todaysDate;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron. the updated one is working fine.